# Import classes hover state to other classes in .LESS

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, less

Just learning .less and using twitters bootstrap in my project.

If i whant an green button for an form to submit i have to write:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
```

But i will be able to skip the class attribute in the input tag.

I will not change the twitter bootstrap file. I will overload them in my default.less file like this:

```
button, input[type="submit"]{ .btn; .btn-success; }
```

But then I do not get the hover state and active state to the button and i get errors if i try to make it like this:

```
button, input[type="submit"]{/* previus code... */ &:hover{ .btn:hover; }}
```

You may notice what i trying to accomplish. I know I can do this in jquery or javascript but i will be able to do this in my .less-file whitout touching orginal bootsrap-files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that that is possible without modifying the Bootstrap CSS.

Are you able to modify the bootstrap CSS at all? If so, you could add a `.btn-hover` class to `.btn:hover`, and then in `button, input[type="submit"]`:

```
&:hover {
    .btn-hover;
    .btn-success-hover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.btn and .btn-success are classes. These classes are define in buttons.less. They call mixin from mixins.less called .buttonBackground. You can call this mixin for your buttons:

```
button, input[type="submit"]{
     .buttonBackground(@startColor,@endColor);
}
```

@startColor and @endColor are for button gradient and the hover state uses the @endColor. 
Or you can change colour in variables.less (btnInfoBackgroundHighlight) to your own.
Or you can use

```
.btn-success{
      &:hover{
           background-color: @yourOwnColor;
      }
}
```